# Sine rule not getting expected output

Tags: c#, trigonometry

This is a small part of a piece of code I'm writing. This uses an equation to calculate the value of y. The equation in degrees is y= 90sin(((2x)/3)-30) and the equation in rations (this is the one I'm using in the code) y = 90sin(((x-45)*pi)/270)

If i have x as 45 or 315 the output should be 0 and if x is 180 then y should 90. This works fine when used on a normal calculator but when trying to write this in to the code it doesn't out correctly.

```
 1. X--------Expected Y---Code Output 
 2. 315--------0----------1.10214571844014E-14
 3. 180-------90----------90 
 4. 45----- ---0-----------0
```

This is the program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Basic_s
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x = 315;
            double sinCon = ((x-45)*Math.PI)/270;
            double sinRad = Math.Sin(sinCon);
            double y= sinRad* 90;
            Console.WriteLine(sinCon.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(sinRad.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(y.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a rounding error because floating point numbers are not precise. 1.10214571844014E-14 is a very small number. It is almost zero.

Comment: As mentioned, you cannot always get exact results because the types have limited precision. If you only care about the output, you could do something like `y.ToString("0.0")`, which will give an output with one decimal place. (Similarly, you could use `"0.00"` for two places, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal calculators doesn't have so much precision as compared to computers. If you see the result in decimal form with out scientific notation, the result is negligible small and close to 0. There fore calculators show this zero. You can use Math.Round for this problem.

```
double y= Math.Round(sinRad* 90,5);
```